# How to migrate datas using .sql script?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Im struggling how to migrate datas using .sql script I'm quite new to SQL and trying to figure out how to migrate data's purely on .SQL. I want to add my old data to the new table as a new record with a different structure

**Here's my case:** I have old two tbl and i want to merge it to my new structured tbl with an additional columns. I'm kinda stuck here since I'm not used in using conditional on .SQL

Prefixes of the tables are schemas

**Old table**

old.groups

| id | group_name |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | Apex |
| 11 | Pred |
| 12 | Tor |

old.sub_groups

| parent_id | sub_group |
| --- | --- |
| 10 | sub-apex |
| 11 | sub-pred |
| 11 | sub-sub-pred |

**New Table**:
Expected Migrated Data

public.new_groups *id is auto incremented

Fresh New populated table

| id | group_name | level | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Apex | 1 | 10 |
| 1 | Pred | 1 | 11 |
| 2 | Tor | null | null |
| 3 | sub-apex | 2 | 10 |
| 4 | sub-pred | 2 | 11 |
| 5 | sub-sub-pred | 2 | 11 |

I want to merge it with conditions. but i can't keep up with SQL queries

**Condition 1:** If old.groups.id doesn't detect any match on old.sub_groups.parent_id it will be inserted to public.new_groups but the public.new_groups.level and public.new_groups.parent_id will be default to null.

**Condition 2:** If old.groups.id detects a match on old.sub_groups.parent_id it will be also inserted to public.new_groups then tag the level as 1 (1 means parent group in my structure) but with another new three inserted records which is the sub_groups it detected refer to tbl.new_groups id [3, 4, and 5] and tag the level as 2. and the parent_id will be the parent_id of the old.sub_groups or the id of the parent in old.groups

This is my unfinished Query im only able to call the data its missing out the conditional and the update but i think this is also wrong:

```
INSERT INTO public.new_groups(
SELECT *, b.sub_group as group_name, b.parent_id FROM old.groups as a 
LEFT JOIN old.sub_groups as b ON a.id = b.parent_id....
)
```

Comment: Is this a migration (moving data from one database to another) or is this just about joining two tables in a query to get expected results? How do both mysql and postgresql come into this question? Are you migrating from one to the other?

Comment: Given your table `sub_groups` how would you determine that `sub_pred` is `4` and `sub-sub-pred` is `5`. There is no column to determine order, so it would make just as much sense that they would be switched (or perhaps you don't care)? Furthermore, is this `mysql` or `postgres`, those are two very different RDBMS produts. Lastly, what is this strange database hierarchy where a table like `sub_group` belongs to ... another table named `tbl`? Is `tbl` a database or schema?

Comment: @Shadow yes sir im migrating one to the other not just queries. but I'm struggling since I'm new to SQL queries. I also edit my post

Comment: Hello @JNevill sorry i just edited my post. the id's of the public.new_groups is auto incremented its a new fresh table that I just want my old datas to be migrated to public.new_groups as new records and I'm using postgres as my RDBMS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE new (
   id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY ,
   group_name VARCHAR(20),
   level INTEGER,
   parent_id INTEGER
);
```

You can copy the tables with this statement:

```
INSERT INTO new(group_name, level, parent_id)
SELECT DISTINCT
    group_name,
    CASE WHEN subgroups.parent_id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 1 END as level,
    subgroups.parent_id
FROM old
LEFT JOIN subgroups ON old.id = subgroups.parent_id

UNION ALL

SELECT
    sub_group,
    2,
    parent_id
FROM subgroups;
```

see: [DBFIDDLE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0e1081380c88dc38b64096f5032a283e)

just my `id` starts with 1, and not with 0.